# Thesaurus Files for Full-Text Search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have implemented full text search in sql server database(2012). I need to modify the Thesaurus Files. I am using webhosting so I do not have the access to that.

I was looking for any sql command that I can use to modify Thesaurus Files by adding new words.

Is it possible? Is there any sql command that I can use to accomplish  this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx#editing

`The thesaurus for a given language can be configured by editing its thesaurus file (an XML file).`

`Only system administrators can update, modify, or delete thesaurus files.`

Comment: Plus Thesaurus is set up for entire instance so it's very unlikely the webhost would allow that, even if technically possible.

Comment: thanks for info. It's kind of limited is what I think